# Error Importing JSON Data into Excel using VBA-JSON

Tags: json, excel, vba

I am using VBA-JSON to Import Json data to excel

I am pulling the JSON data from an API by making a GET request

The JSON data looks like :

```
{"TotalArea":{"CM":326.18,"mm":3261.8}}
```

Code I am using for importing this data into excel :

```
Public Sub exceljson()
    Dim http As Object, JSON As Object, i As Integer

    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    http.Open "GET", "http://api.demosite.com/totalar", False
    http.Send
    Set JSON = ParseJson(http.responseText)

    i = 2
    For Each Item In JSON
        Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = Item("TotalArea")("CM")
        Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value = Item("TotalArea")("mm")
        i = i + 1
    Next

    MsgBox ("complete")
End Sub
```

Running the above code gives me "Type mismatch" Error.

Comment: You don't define `Item`

Comment: And on what line is the error?

Comment: defining Item doesn't solve it either

Comment: Without the whole program, it will be hard to troubleshoot.  But what do you see if you click `Debug > Compile VBAProject`?  Also, under `Tools > References`, do you have `Microsoft XML, v6.0` and `Microsoft HTML Object Library` selected?

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all, there is no json file on http://api.demosite.com/totalar . 
So the 1st step is to check that, when you call the url, there is a json file behind
for example:  use http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users 
Pre requisite  :

1. Include Microsoft Scripting Runtime in your references
2. add in your project https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas